# Strange behaviour whilst setting style.display in a simple function loop

Tags: javascript

Consider the following JavaScript:

```
function step(show)
{
    for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        document.getElementById('step' + show).style.display = show == i ? 'block' : 'none';
    }
}

step(2);
```

In combination with this HTML:

```
<div id="step1">1</div>
<div id="step2">2</div>
<div id="step3">3</div>
<div id="step4">4</div>
<div id="step5">5</div>
```

I'd expect only `#step2` to be shown, but instead I see the opposite result:

```
1
3
4
5
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3REbr/). What is causing this strange behaviour and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want:

```
document.getElementById('step' + i).style.display = show == i ? 'block' : 'none';
```

Notice the change here ------------------------^

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/5DNjc/2/

Without the change, you're always modifying the element with an `id` using the passed in parameter (static). So technically, you're always setting the `display` (of the target element) based on whether the last element passes the condition. The changing value is `i`.

To me, it makes it more readable if you separate out the logic, and might've helped you not encounter the problem in the first place :) Something like:

```
function step(show) {
    for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        var curDiv = document.getElementById('step' + i);
        var shouldBeShown = (i === show);
        var newDisplay = shouldBeShown ? 'block' : 'none';
        curDiv.style.display = newDisplay;
    }
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/5DNjc/3/

Comment: Jesus, it's been a long night (all nighter). Thanks for spotting my stupid mistake Ian!

Comment: @DannyBeckett Haha no problem. It happens to everyone. I added something extra to the end of my answer that might help. Let me know if you're having any more trouble with this :)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('step' + i).style.display = show == i ? 'block' : 'none';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3REbr/2/